# Local notification sound not works in foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   localNotification.alertBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"meeting schedule from %@ ",[namelist objectAtIndex:i]];

        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
         localNotification.soundName = @"meetting.mp3";

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"timerInvoked" object:self];
```

I am using these code for `create local notification`.The local notification sound works in Background,`but when Enters to foreground only notification fire without sound`.

Please help me to solve this problem..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation on UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers
>   the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound
>   is played. However, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is
>   called if the application delegate implements it. The
>   UILocalNotification instance is passed into this method, and the
>   delegate can check its properties or access any custom data from the
>   userInfo dictionary.

So, You are not able to play sound in foreground but another option is you can use `AVAudioPlayer` for play notification sound.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],notification.soundName]];

AVAudioPlayer *newAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
self.audioPlayer = newAudioPlayer;
self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[self.audioPlayer play];
```